# How do I save model changes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to update my database but I have an invalid argument in the `SaveChanges()` statement.

What am I doing wrong?

```
foreach (ViewModels.QuestionVM0 f in qe.QuestionOptions0)
{
    // loop through records to update
    int aID = qe.ActivityID.Value;
    int tID = qe.TaskID.Value;
    int qNo = f.QuestionNo.Value;

    Models.question1 questionCreate = new question1();

    questionCreate.ActivityID = aID;
    questionCreate.TaskID = tID;
    questionCreate.QuestionNo = qNo;


    db.SaveChanges(questionCreate);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will work well:

```
int aID, tID, qNo;
Models.question1 questionCreate;

foreach (ViewModels.QuestionVM0 f in qe.QuestionOptions0)
{
    // loop through records to update
    aID = qe.ActivityID.Value;
    tID = qe.TaskID.Value;
    qNo = f.QuestionNo.Value;

    questionCreate = new question1();

    questionCreate.ActivityID = aID;
    questionCreate.TaskID = tID;
    questionCreate.QuestionNo = qNo;


    // For Insert new row
    db.question1.Add(questionCreate);

    // For Update exsisting row
    db.Entry(questionCreate).State = EntityState.Modified;

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

You may call db.SaveChanges() after the loop.

Comment: if I am not wrong its `db.Entry(questionCreate).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: hi guys sorry for late reply i got this error while saving changes.  Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass anything to `SaveChanges` method. EF (I guess you use it) keeps tracking all your changes so it already knows what has to be updated.

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

Btw, you shouldn't call `SaveChanges` on every iteration. Call it after `foreach` instead to get SQL reached only once, not for every row again and again.